# How do I echo a file path after interpreting characters like dots '.' and tildes '~'?

Tags: bash, scripts, special-characters, echo

I want to write a bash script that accepts, as an input argument, a file specification that includes one or more uses of the special characters `.`, `..`, and `~`.  I want my script's output to echo Bash's full path interpretation of my script.

Here is script I have tried:

```
a=$(ls -l -o -g "${1}" | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1-6 --complement -)

echo "\\"${a}\\""
```

If I issue command: `myscript ~/.local/../.profile`

The result returned is: `/home/OldManK/.local/../.profile`. But, I want: `/home/OldManK/.profile`.

Another example: `myscript ~/./.profile` returns: `/home/OldManK/./.profile`, but, I want: `/home/OldManK/.profile`.

Another (executed from `/home/OldManK/.local`): `myscript ../.profile` returns: `../.profile`, but, I want: `/home/OldManK/.profile`.

Any alternate approaches, please?

Comment: Please "edit" your post and use code formatting for your code: that will greatly increase readability of your post and increase the chance someone reads it entirely through.

Comment: As a general rule, parsing `ls` is a very bad idea that should be avoided unless you have 100% control over the input file names, but even then it will break when using `-l` since the dates can change. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Note that it isn't actually bash responsible for parsing things like `../` -- this is done by the operating system kernel as part of handling `open()` and similar calls.

Comment: Expansion of the `~` is done by the calling shell before it's passed to your script as an argument. That is, when you run `myscript ~/.local/../.profile`, the script actually receives "/home/OldManK/.local/../.profile" as its argument. If you want your script to handle `~` itself, things get more complicated (see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)).

Comment: What you're looking for is sometimes called the "canonical" form of a path, with `foo/../bar` resolved (to `bar` if foo wasn't a symlink.)  [What's a "canonical path"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12100299) .  The other part is shell-expansion of shell meta-characters like `~`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `realpath`:

```
$ realpath ~/.local/bin/../mycommand
/home/user/.local/mycommand
```

From [man realpath](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html):

```
DESCRIPTION
    Print the resolved absolute file name; all but the last component must exist
```

Comment: Thanks, Jos.  Perfect.

Comment: If my post was helpful, please check the mark next to it to mark the question as answered. Thanks.